# Magento 1.9 - How to filter catalog_product.list with their custom attribute in soap/v1

Tags: magento-1.9, soap, soap-api-v1

```
$client     = new SoapClient('http://localhost/project/api/soap/?wsdl');

$user_name  = $_POST["user_name"];
$password   = $_POST["password"];

$response = array();

$session    = $client->login($user_name, $password);
$result     = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list');

$response = array(
    "status" => 1,
    "message" => "suceess",
    "featute_products" => $result
);

ob_start();
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-control: private');
header('Expires: -1');

echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the code snippet to below

```
$session    = $client->login($user_name, $password);
$filters = array(
    'sku' => array('like'=>'zol%')
);

$products = $client->call($session, 'product.list', array($filters));
```

For more information refer : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalogProduct.html

Comment: I have added a custom attribute which is not there in returning array...so how can i get array with that particular attribute and than apply filters ?